# How to select first tab-separated column in first line?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I would like to `grep -o` the date... only the first value in line 1 from a tab-separated file with PowerShell v2.

I used the following command to get the first line:

```
Get-Content "C:\filepath\file.txt" | select -first 1
```

How can get also the first column of this line? Or via Regex?

Sample:

```
15.03.2017          22:42:49                              uSecAction                                                        =             4
15.03.2017          22:42:49                              uAction_Program                                                          =             5
15.03.2017          22:42:49                              uSecAction_Program                                    =             4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet should help you to get the first column of the tab separated file :

```
  Get-Content "d:\my docs\file.txt" |select -first 1| %{ ($_ -split "\t+")[0]}
```